# AddHandler has error: xxx is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net

[image]

Here is the event definition

```
Public MustInherit Class CBaseLetterParser
    Public Event onKeywordUnhandled(ByVal sKeyword As String)
    ...
End Class

Public Class CCreditCardLetterParser
    Inherits CBaseLetterParser
    ...
End Class
```

What's the correct way to subscribe the onKeywordUnhandled event?

I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: I believe the problem is related to the instance: your LetterBuilder is an instance of CreditCards. I guess you need to AddHandler to CreditCard itself and only after this, instance it in LetterBuilder.

Comment: `AddHandler letterbuilder.onKeywordUnhandled, AddressOf f`

Comment: @LarsTech You are awesome!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The AddHandler method wants the actual event that you created, so instead of

```
AddHandler onKeyworkUnhandledEventHandler, AddressOf f
```

use

```
AddHandler onKeyworkUnhandled, AddressOf f
```